# How to use curl with superagent/fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, superagent

I am trying to wire up my app to an external API. The external API's [documentation](https://www.wordsapi.com/docs/) says to make the call using `curl`:

```
curl "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/soliloquy"
  -H "X-Mashape-Key: <required>"
```

My app is built with JS/React - I am unfamiliar with the above syntax. I am trying to figure out how to write this using `superagent` (or, if necessary, `fetch`).

This is what I have so far from following some other Stack Overflow answers but I have no idea how to incorporate: `-H "X-Mashape-Key: <required>"`

My API key is stored in a `.env` file.

```
require('dotenv').config
console.log(process.env) 
const request = require('superagent')
const url = 'https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/'

//dictionary
export function getDictionaryDefinition(word) {
  return request.get(`${url}/dog`).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend getting familiar with the basics of `curl`. It's worth knowing and it's everywhere. you can find nice cheat sheets [here](https://opensource.com/sites/default/files/gated-content/curl-cheat-sheet.pdf) and [here](https://devhints.io/curl).

`-H` in `curl` represent a header, so in your case you'll need to add that to your request, e.g.

```js
request.get(`${url}/dog`)
  .set('X-Mashape-Key', API_KEY)
  .then((response) => {...
```

or in fetch:

```js
fetch("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/soliloquy", {
  headers: {
    "X-Mashape-Key": API_KEY
  }
})
```

as a bonus, I found a nice project that "translates" `curl` to `fetch`: https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/